# Understanding the Sort Algorithm in Groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy, closures

Why is the second item in an array the first element (a) when we use sort. 
Look at this example, is there something I'm not getting?

```
def array = [4,2,7]


def listSorter = {a,b -> 

      println "a: " + a;
      println "b: " + b;
      a <=>b;

}
array = array.sort(listSorter);
println array;
```

prints this:

```
a: 2
b: 4
a: 7
b: 2
a: 7
b: 4
[2, 4, 7]
```

Comment: The order of parameters doesn't matter does it? It's an implementation detail

Comment: Yeah that's true, I guess I'm trying to understand what the sorting mechanism here is. How is it sorting?. Why is  a, b -> a <=> b doing a asc sort, while a, b -> b <=> a  is doing a desc sort?
I'm assuming a <=> b is equal to (a > b) ? return 1 : (a < b) ? return -1 : return 0; what is the relationship of 1, -1, and 0 in the sort?  Are -1 elements put in the beginning, and 1 elements at the end of the array?

Comment: Yes, the same as a comparator

Answer (score 1):

When you ask Groovy to sort your items, it is not processed in order.  Groovy uses the collections sort under the covers.  This can sort in multiple ways.  The legacy way is merge sort.  If you are in Java 8 for example, it will do a TimSort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort depending if you have legacy merge sort (Arrays.LegacyMergeSort.userRequested) turned on.  Compared to a basic bubble sort, the algorithm does not just run through the list in order and compare each item.  This is why when you put prints in the comparator, it seems random what is being compared - This is just an optimization to make the sorting faster.